# Sticking borders of table-cell divs to wrapper div in table layout

Tags: html, css, css-float, tablelayout

I'm going to use table layout for a wrapper div which will contain a number of divs (suppose it is a list of products, 5 in a row).

The problem is that when I set wrapper's style to display:table and 
border-spacing: 25px , this border is also being applied to side divs (e.g. suppose I have 5 divs and I don't want my leftest div has left margin and also don't want my rightest div has right margin. I want my leftest div stick to the left border of wrapper div and the same about my rightest div.)

I tried & searched a lot but I found no proper solution and in every solution, the gap between rightest and leftest divs with the wrapping div remains.

Can you please help me resolving this issue?

Comment: Can you post your code / a demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually it depends on your real markup, but one option is wrapping the table by an `inline-block` element having `overflow: hidden` and also giving the table a negative left/right margin:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table {
  background-color: gold;
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 25px;
  margin: 0 -25px;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">foo</div>
      <div class="col">bar</div>
      <div class="col">baz</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Merci Hashem jan, Let me check it

Comment: Thanks a lot, Your solution was helpful.